# Remove invalid characters from XML

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a function/procedure in Oracle to remove invalid XML characters from a `varchar2`?

I need this because I want to generate an XML from the database and some `varchar2` data has invalid control characters(see below) that I need to strip out.

I'm concerned about the control characters with code below `U+0020`:

[U+0009, U+000A, U+000D: these are the only C0 controls accepted in XML 1.0;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML)

I checked `DBMS_XMLGEN` and didn't find anything suitable.

Is there something or do I have to program it myself?

Comment: Do you want to remove them or encode them?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your database character code is UTF8 and those charaters are valid from point of view of the database.
Then you may simple replace them to a blank or NULL to get rid of them.

e.g.

```
replace(str,UNISTR('\000D'),null)
```

Comment: Yes, I can replace all control characters, but I was hoping that Oracle provided such a pre-build function e.g. `DBMS_XMLGEN.Remove_invalid_characters()`

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(UNISTR('\000D')) from dual`

Comment: `select case when DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(UNISTR('\000D')) is null then 'null' else 'not null' end from dual;` returns 'not null'

Answer (score 0):

This function will replace illegal xml characters with the corresponding replacement value `dbms_xmlgen.convert()`